# Interactive skimage viewer canvastools RectangleTool

Tags: python, image-processing, interactive, scikit-image, viewer

I've run into trouble with `skimage.viewer.canvastools.RectangleTool()` and would be grateful for any help that could be offered.

I would like the selection box to be interactive i.e. after drawing, one can edit the selected region using the handles. This feature [appears to work](https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html) with `matplotlib.widgets.RectangleSelector()`...e.g.

```
from matplotlib.widgets import  RectangleSelector
from pylab import *

def onselect(eclick, erelease):
  'Dummy function'

x = arange(100)/(99.0)
y = sin(x)
fig = figure
ax = subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)

test = RectangleSelector(ax, onselect,
                         drawtype='box',
                         interactive=True)
show()
```

---

However, with `skimage.viewer.canvastools.RectangleTool()`when I use

```
rect_tool = RectangleTool(viewer,
                      on_enter=save_region,
                      interactive=True)
```

I'm thrown:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'interactive'

...and if I use

```
rect_tool = RectangleTool(viewer,
                      on_enter=save_region,
                      rect_props=dict(interactive=True))
```

I'm thrown this error:

> AttributeError: Unknown property interactive

Have I misunderstood the [manpage](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.viewer.canvastools.html#skimage.viewer.canvastools.RectangleTool)?

Many thanks!

---

This is where I am at (RectangleTool not interactive):

```
import skimage.io
from skimage.viewer import ImageViewer
from skimage.viewer.canvastools import RectangleTool

import numpy as np

from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.simpledialog import askfloat


Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
print(filename)

image_rgb = skimage.io.imread(filename)
image_r = image_rgb[:,:,0] # extract red channel


########
# Does this need to be initialised differently to make the rectangle interactive?
viewer = ImageViewer(image_r)


intensity_dumps = [] # used to store pixel values for selected regions

def save_region(extents):
    global image_r, intensity_dumps
    xmin = np.floor(extents[0]).astype('uint16')
    xmax = np.ceil(extents[1]).astype('uint16')
    ymin = np.floor(extents[2]).astype('uint16')
    ymax = np.ceil(extents[3]).astype('uint16')
    region = image_r[ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax]
    intensity_dumps.append(np.ndarray.flatten(region))
    print('Mean:',np.mean(region))
    print('Std. dev.:',np.std(region))
    print('Max:',np.max(region))


########
# Here is where I believe the problem lies...
rect_tool = RectangleTool(viewer,
                          on_enter=save_region)


thresholded = viewer.show()[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Juan for some useful suggestions.

My aim was to have sliders and an interactive rectangle selector. In the end I decided not to use `scikit-image` libraries and instead use `matplotlib` directly.

This is a simplified version of my code for others who might find it helpful when facing similar issues in the future:

```
from matplotlib.widgets import  RectangleSelector
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider

def onselect(eclick, erelease):
  'Dummy function'

# Lists to store pixel values
intensity_dumps = []

def toggle_selector(event):
    #print(' Key pressed.')
    if event.key in ['Q', 'q'] and toggle_selector.RS.active:
        print(' RectangleSelector deactivated.')
        toggle_selector.RS.set_active(False)
    if event.key in ['B', 'b']:
        extents = toggle_selector.RS.extents
        xmin = np.floor(extents[0]).astype('uint16')
        xmax = np.ceil(extents[1]).astype('uint16')
        ymin = np.floor(extents[2]).astype('uint16')
        ymax = np.ceil(extents[3]).astype('uint16')
#        print(xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax)
        intensity_dumps.append(image_cropped[ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax])


ax = plt.subplot(111)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2, bottom=0.11, top=0.99)

#plt.xlabel('x (pixels)')
#plt.ylabel('y (pixels)')
ax.set_title('Select region; type <b> to save to list')

img = ax.imshow(image, interpolation='nearest', cmap='terrain')
cb = plt.colorbar(img)


ax_cmin = plt.axes([0.2, 0.01, 0.65, 0.03])
ax_cmax  = plt.axes([0.2, 0.06, 0.65, 0.03])

s_cmin = Slider(ax_cmin, 'min percentile', 0, 100, valinit=1)
s_cmax = Slider(ax_cmax, 'max percentile', 0, 100, valinit=99)

def update(val, s=None):
    min_display = np.percentile(image, s_cmin.val)
    max_display = np.percentile(image, s_cmax.val)
    img.set_clim([min_display, max_display])
    plt.draw()

s_cmin.on_changed(update)
s_cmax.on_changed(update)

toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(ax,
                                       onselect,
                                       spancoords='pixels',
                                       drawtype='box',
                                       interactive=True)
plt.connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you have misunderstood. Notice that there is no `interactive=` argument to the `RectangleTool`. Instead, there is a `rect_props` argument, which is a **dictionary**. The dictionary items will be passed as keyword arguments to `RectangleSelector`. So you want: `RectangleTool(..., rect_props=dict(interactive=True)`.

Comment: Thanks Juan. Unfortunately using `rect_props=dict(interactive=True)` threw a different error: "AttributeError: Unknown property interactive"...

Comment: Oooooh. Sorry, I misread the documentation. (like you LOL). `rect_props` are properties for `patches.Rectangle`, that is, visual features of the patch. Based on [the code](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/blob/35ef2171e0da60e5d8f68c6c29b8e183a5c35a19/skimage/viewer/canvastools/recttool.py#L65-L110), it doesn't look like there is a way to pass `interactive=True` to `RectangleSelector`. However, later parts of the code make me think it should allow resizing anyway. If you ignore `interactive`, are you not able to resize?

Comment: Nice suggestion :) Unfortunately `active_handle` is already `True` (setting it to `False` completely prevents interaction).

Comment: I see on the `RectangleTool` that the _init_ uses Matplotlib's `RectangleSelector`...which in my example does accept `interactive=True` as an argument. If this argument could be passed into scikit-image's `RectangleTool` initialisation then I guess we would be up and running - is this right?

Comment: I think that's right. You could install skimage from source, change that line, and see if it works. http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/install.html If it does, we would welcome a pull request to add this!